# Output json with double quotes for laravel blade

Tags: json, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a problem with the JSON obtained for a request with LARAVEL 8

In my controler

```
$tmpMenu = 
Menu::leftJoin('bookings', 'menus.date_menu', '=', 'bookings.date_reservation')
->get();
$finalTab2 = $tmpMenu->toJson();
```

In app.blade.php

```
events: '{{!! $finalTab2 !!}}',
```

My JSON is like this

```
'{[{
  "id": 19,
  "description": null,
  "meal": "chips"
}]}'
```

I think that to work it has to be like this

```
'{[{
{
  "id": "19",
  "description": "",
  "meal": "chips"
}]}'
```

How to then automatically add quotes to all values ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

In app.blade.php

```
@if(isset($finalTab2))
     events: @json($finalTab2),
 @endif
```